# I can't seem to 'Log In' to Geforce Experience?

Tags: windows-10, streaming, nvidia-geforce-experience

I have an Nvidia Shield tablet and when I try to gamestream, it tells me to log in to the GeForce Experience. When I go to GeForce Experience on my laptop I don't see the 'Log in' button next to Shadowplay.

How am I supposed to stream games?